# find mean or median date of event

Tags: matlab, date

I have a dataset for which I have extracted the date at which an event occurred. The date is in the format of MMDDYY although MatLab does not show leading zeros so often it's MDDYY.

Is there a method to find the mean or median (I could use either) date? `median` works fine when there is an odd number of days but for even numbers I believe it is averaging the two middle ones which doesn't produce sensible values. I've been trying to convert the dates to a MatLab format with `regexp` and put it back together but I haven't gotten it to work.  Thanks

```
dates=[32381 41081  40581  32381  32981 41081   40981  40581];
```

Comment: " I've been trying to convert the dates to a MatLab format"... what exactly have you tried? Do you realize that `x % 100` and `floor(x/100)` suffice to split the numbers into YY, DD, and M or MM?

Comment: Sorry, no. What does x % 100 do? I'm not familiar with that use of %. Doesn't everything after it get commented out?

Comment: yes, but arne.b is using the dollar sign as it is usually used: the modulo operator. In matlab however, the modulo operator doesn't exist and you'll have to use the modulo function ''mod''

Comment: Thanks @GuntherStruyf I had never heard of the modulo operator and was confused by the `%` that arne.b and Dan Nissenbaum used in their solutions but it makes sense now. I'd been looking at MATLAB too long to realize that a simple `/10^x` could separate the numbers! Way easier than splitting as a string

Comment: oops, sorry. I was confusing languages. As noted by Gunther, I meant the mod function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [datenum](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html) to convert dates to a serial date number (1 at 01/01/0000, 2 at 02/01/0000, 367 at 01/01/0001, etc.):

```
strDate='27112011';
numDate = datenum(strDate,'ddmmyyyy')
```

Any arithmetic operation can then be performed on these date numbers, like taking a mean or median:

```
mean(numDates)
median(numDates)
```

The only problem here, is that you don't have your dates in a string type, but as numbers. Luckily datenum also accepts numeric input, but you'll have to give the day, month and year separated in a vector:

```
numDate = datenum([year month day])
```

or as rows in a matrix if you have multiple timestamps.

So for your specified example data:

```
dates=[32381 41081  40581  32381  32981 41081   40981  40581];
years  = mod(dates,100);
dates  = (dates-years)./100;
days   = mod(dates,100);
months = (dates-days)./100;
years = years + 1900; % set the years to the 20th century

numDates = datenum([years(:) months(:) days(:)]);
fprintf('The mean date is %s\n', datestr(mean(numDates)));
fprintf('The median date is %s\n', datestr(median(numDates)));
```

In this example I converted the resulting mean and median back to a readable date format using [datestr](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/datestr.html), which takes the serial date number as input.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. I should have mentioned I was aware of datenum and datestr but it wasn't apparent to me how to get my dates into a form that MATLAB would recognize.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dates=[32381 41081 40581 32381 32981 41081 40981 40581];
d=zeros(1,length(dates));
for i=1:length(dates)
    d(i)=datenum(num2str(dates(i)),'ddmmyy');
end
m=mean(d);
m_str=datestr(m,'dd.mm.yy')
```

I hope this info to be useful, regards

Comment: Thanks! I think this will be easiest to use although with `mmddyy`... crazy Americans and their pseudostandards :)

Comment: no, it doesn't work. I was also my first tought, but it messes up because of the missing zeros; So 1052012 gets translated to 10th of may 2012 instead of the first of may 2012 :/

Comment: It looks like it may work in the case of MMDDYY or MDDYY as opposed to DDMMYY as you were saying. Possibly pure coincidence but `datestr(datenum(num2str('10512','mmddyy')))` yields 01-May-2012

Comment: But unfortunately you can't seem to use dates(:) to do a whole array. I was hoping I could use one line: `datestr(median(datenum(num2str(dates(:),'mmddyy'))))`

Comment: mmz, I might have been mistaken on this. I was testing on octave, which behaves as I said in my first comment. When testing now in matlab, I see that matlab itself doesn't make that mistake..  
@Dominik: you misplaced a hook
`datestr(mean(datenum(num2str(dates(:)),'mmddyy')))`  
does work (in matlab). For future reference, (speed) and good practices I would still use my answer :p

Comment: you are correct, it does work with the vector `dates`. However when I attempted it with my data it did not work :( `datestr(datenum(num2str(peakSWE.(fn{1}).date(1,:)),'mmddyy'))` returns `17-Aug-0003` instead of an array of  dates. `(fn{1})` is simply the first field of my structure and date is a 31x25 double and I would like (eventually) the average of each row. Do I need different syntax for this? In the future I will reformat my dates at the beginning with mod but I don't want to open up that can of worms right now.

Comment: the input to `num2str` must be a column vector, else the result will be one char array of length Nx5 instead of N strings of length 5 ('mmddyy'). That's why I used dates(:), that transforms dates no matter what in a column vector. You'll first have to convert your rows into columns, which is of course also possible with the transpose operator `'`. Try again with `.date(1,:)'` ;)

Comment: the input to num2str must be a column vector, else the result will be one char array of length Nx5 instead of N strings of length 5 ('mmddyy'). That's why I used dates(:), that transforms dates no matter what in a column vector. You'll first have to convert your rows into columns, which is of course also possible with the transpose operator '. Try again with .date(1,:)' ;)

Answer (score 0):

Store the dates as YYMMDD, rather than as MMDDYY.  This has the useful side effect that the numeric order of the dates is also the chronological order.

Here is the pseudo-code for a function that you could write.

```
foreach date:
    year = date % 100
    date = (date - year) / 100
    day = date % 100
    date = (date - day) / 100
    month = date
    newdate = year * 100 * 100 + month * 100 + day
end for
```

Once you have the dates in YYMMDD format, then find the median (numerically), and this is also the median chronologically.

Comment: This didn't make any sense to me until @GuntherStruyf commented about the modulo operator. MATLAB uses `mod()` instead of `%`. Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

You see above how to present dates as numbers.

I will add no your issue of finding median of the list.  The default matlab `median` function will average the two middle values when there are an even number of values.

But you can do it yourself!  Try this:

```
dates; % is your array of dates in numeric form
sdates = sort(dates);
mediandate = sdates(round((length(sdates)+1)/2));
```

Comment: I suppose the advantage is I can round to the nearest day? How is that different from `round(median(dates))`?

Comment: you were concerned I thought with coming up with a median date that was not in your list of dates.  This gives you as close to the median value as you want and still have a date in your list.  Where this might be usefuL: maybe you need to come up with a weekday, so you have only weekdays in your list.  THis would give you a weekday for sure.